# Android Q - Query MediaStore for audioFiles in specific folder and its subfolders

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I'm trying to query Android Q mediaStore using contentResolver. I want to get all audiofiles from a **specific** Folder with all its subdirectories (for example `/sdcard/Download/AudioFiles/Folder 1` and `/sdcard/Download/AudioFiles/Folder 2/Folder 3`).
Perrmission `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is set in my `manifest.xml` and also runtime permissions are used.

I did this in Android Studio Emulator, thats why I use `download` folder

When I select folder `Downloads` in `fileChooser` to get all audiofiles in the subdirecories I got no results (`Cursor.getCount() = 0`).
When I select the directory `/sdcard/Download/AudioFiles/Folder 2` I got the expected results.

This behaviour comes from `DocumentFile.getName()`which gives me the last part of the filesystem.
The fileChosser selection `Downloads` gives me `download`. Please not the plurals "s" is missing. So I don't catch a result.

I get selected directory name using in `onActivityResult` from

```
Intent intent = new vntent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
```

and then

```
uri = data.getData();
Documentfile df = DocumentFile.getName();
```

I get all audiofiles in a folder using:

```
selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " like ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {audiodir};
```

When I set

```
selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH + " like ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {audiodir};
```

I get no audifiles listened.

Total code:

```
Uri uri;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
}
String directory = "audioFiles"
String audiodir = "%" + directory + "%";

projection = new String[]{
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR,
};

Cursor cur;
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH + " like ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {audiodir};
String sortOder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK + " ASC";
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOder);
```

In Android Q `mediaStore.audio.media.DATA` is depricated so I use `mediaStore.audio.media.RELATIVE_PATH` instead.

How can I solve this behavior (cut the plural "s" is a bad Workaround).

Thanks,
FP

Comment: `(for example AudioFiles/Folder` That is not a specific folder. Please try again. What do you mean with `AudioFiles` ? That is not a folder. `Folder` in `/storage/emulated/0/Music/Folder` would be a specific folder.

Comment: `Permissions set in my manifest.xml and when I choose the Folder in fileChooser.` ?? Which permission did you set? And why? And which folder did you choose? Put all in your post please.

Comment: For audio you should use ALBUM and ALBUM_ID.

Comment: `I get all audiofiles in a folder using:`. Well nice? But then i do not understand what you want more.

Comment: I got some new insight and have adapted the post

Comment: It makes no sense to let the user select a folder and then query the media store for its content. Why dont you just list the files your self in that directory?

Comment: Use ALBUM to select a folder if audio. Not BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME. Second time i tell you.

Comment: "Why dont you just list the files your self in that directory?" - because then i have to search the whole structure, the mediastore has already done that. i think it is much faster this way

Comment: "Use ALBUM" - why should i select by album. i don't know the structure in which a user stores his audio files, he can put all files in one directory or one directory for each album. the album name is also not known to the user, he only knows the directory name